# Как изменить сортировку таблицы в Lua таким образом, чтобы русские строки были раньше английских?

Tags: lua

Как изменить сортировку таблицы в Lua таким образом, чтобы русские строки были раньше английских?
Сейчас я делаю это двумя отсортированными таблицами. Сначала вывожу русские сокращения из первой таблицы, а потом английские из второй.
Думаю, что существует более изящный способ решения данной задачи.

```
tbl=tbl or {}
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ЯНАО", desc="Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ОГКМ", desc="Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="LED", desc="Light emitting diode"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="FET", desc="Field effect transistor"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ЛПР", desc="Лицо, принимающее решения"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="БД", desc="База данных"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="P2P", desc="Peer-to-Peer"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="XML", desc="extensible markup language"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="HTTP", desc="Hypertext Transfer Protocol"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="SCADA", desc="Supervisory control and data acquisition"})

print("-----------")

table.sort(tbl, function (a,b) return (a.abbr < b.abbr) end)
for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
print(i, n.abbr, n.desc)
end
```

Нужен такой результат:

```
-----------
1   БД  База данных
2   ЛПР Лицо, принимающее решения
3   ОГКМ    Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение
4   ЯНАО    Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ
5   FET Field effect transistor
6   HTTP    Hypertext Transfer Protocol
7   LED Light emitting diode
8   P2P Peer-to-Peer
9   SCADA   Supervisory control and data acquisition
10  XML extensible markup language
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно воспользоваться тем,  что у латинских букв код символа меньше 127, и немного поменять функцию сортировки, приклеив к началу аббревиатур 0 или 1:

```
tbl=tbl or {}
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ЯНАО", desc="Ямало-ненецкий автономный округ"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ОГКМ", desc="Оренбургское газоконденсатное месторождение"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="LED", desc="Light emitting diode"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="FET", desc="Field effect transistor"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="ЛПР", desc="Лицо, принимающее решения"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="БД", desc="База данных"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="P2P", desc="Peer-to-Peer"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="XML", desc="extensible markup language"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="HTTP", desc="Hypertext Transfer Protocol"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="SCADA", desc="Supervisory control and data acquisition"})

print("-----------")

local function isLatinAscii(s)
  if string.len(s) > 0 then   
     local b = s:byte(1)
     -- Вариант когда весь диапазон с латиницей перемещаем вниз, 
     -- а разные символы и цифры будут выше
     return (b>=65 and b<=90 or b>=97 and b<=122) and 1 or 0
     -- Вариант когда символы между заглавными и строчными латинскими _,[]^ будут ниже латиницы, 
     -- как в обычной сортировке:
     -- return (b>=65 and b<=122) and 1 or 0
  else return 1
  end
end

table.sort(tbl, function (a,b) return (isLatinAscii(a.abbr) .. a.abbr < isLatinAscii(b.abbr) .. b.abbr) end)

for i,n in ipairs(tbl) do
 print(i, n.abbr, n.desc)
end
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Тут проблема будет при таких входных данных (цифры и спецсимволы):
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="1-SCADA", desc="1 Supervisory control and data acquisition"})
table.insert(tbl, {abbr="!", desc="!22222"})
Я наверное должен был сразу в пример добавить эти варианты.
Нужно только поменять местами русские и латинские буквы. Если Вам не сложно, то взгляните еще раз. Может есть решение. Тут наверное как-то нужно диапазон задать.

Comment: Как вариант в начало всех английских слов добавить "ЯЯ".

Comment: а где должны быть цифры? выше всех или ниже русских букв?

Comment: поправил код, думаю дальше не трудно будет под свои нужды поправить диапазоны, зная коды символов, например `string.byte("A") == 65`

Comment: Как обычно  в начале спецсимволы, потом цифры. Только русские перед английскими: 1 ! !22222
2 1-SCADA 1 Supervisory control and data acquisition
<Тут русские>
3 FET Field effect transistor
4 HTTP Hypertext Transfer Protocol
5 LED Light emitting diode

Comment: Так вот не лучше определять латинские слова?
local str = "dddВВ"
--local str = "a"
print(string.find(string.sub(str, 1, 1), "%a"))

Comment: можно и так, но это тоже самое, больше кода просто, да и с кодами символов нагляднее

Comment: Спасибо, @Mike V.